# DISTINCT with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql

I have a query to ask

Table Fruit

```
 FruitID |  Fruit  | Unit Price 
    1    |  Orange |     $3
    2    |  Apple  |     $2
    3    |  Grape  |     $4
```

Table FruitDetails

```
Picture      | Color   | FruitID
Orange_o.jpg | Orange  |    1
Apple_g.jpg  | Green   |    2
Apple_r.jpg  | Red     |    2
Grape_p.jpg  | Purple  |    3
Grape_g.jpg  | Green   |    3
```

The result I want to get is all the fruits with no repeated names.

Example

```
Fruit | UnitPrice | Picture      | Color
Orange|    $3     | Orange_o.jpg | Orange
Apple |    $2     | Apple_g.jpg  | Green
Grape |    $4     | Grape_p.jpg  | Purple
```

Is that possible to make that happen? 
Thanks

Comment: What are you joining on? What does you query look like now?

Comment: How do you select the correct row from `FruitDetails`? How do you know that Grape is Purple and Apple is Green?

Comment: i am not sure that is why i ask if this is possible. this is just an example. the one that i am using is on furniture. so is it possible to make it happen?

Comment: i am joining two tables, fruit and fruit details to produce the result

Comment: You can't join the tables as you wrote them, because there is no column to join them on. The FruitDetails needs to say which fruit each line applies to. Mistakes like this show that you are not actually trying it out.

Comment: Oops. Forgot to write the ID inside. Just updated the tables

Answer (score 1):

Writing for SQL Server, but the actual query should work on other databases.

Setup data:

```
declare @Fruit table (FruitID int not null,Fruit varchar(10) not null,UnitPrice int not null)
insert into @Fruit(FruitID,Fruit,UnitPrice) values
(1,'Orange',3),
(2,'Apple',2),
(3,'Grape',4)

declare @FruitDetails table (FruitID int not null,Picture varchar(20) not null,Color varchar(10) not null)
insert into @FruitDetails (FruitID,Picture,Color) values
(1,'Orange_o.jpg','Orange'),
(3,'Grape_p.jpg','Purple'),
(3,'Grape_g.jpg','Green'),
(2,'Apple_g.jpg','Green'),
(2,'Apple_r.jpg','Red')
```

Query:

```
select
    f.Fruit,
    f.UnitPrice,
    fd.Picture,
    fd.Color
from
    @Fruit f
        inner join
    @FruitDetails fd
        on
            f.FruitID = fd.FruitID
        left join
    @FruitDetails fd_anti
        on
            f.FruitID = fd_anti.FruitID and
            fd_anti.Picture < fd.Picture --This is the condition for picking a better row
where
    fd_anti.FruitID is null --This eliminates rows where a better row was picked
```

Results:

```
Fruit      UnitPrice   Picture              Color
---------- ----------- -------------------- ----------
Orange     3           Orange_o.jpg         Orange
Grape      4           Grape_g.jpg          Green
Apple      2           Apple_g.jpg          Green
```

Which doesn't match your expected result, but you haven't given us a good definition for the condition on picking the "best" row from `FruitDetail`.

Comment: The downside of using left join is that you are limiting the query optimizer. Choosing "best" picture by nested select or another, grouped, join limits it less.

Comment: @JanHudec - If there's a complex multi-column condition required to find the "best" result row, I can express it with the anti-join, but not with a nested select.

Comment: Yes, if you can't calculate number or value representing the order, the nested select, nor really the grouped join, can be used.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "pick any one" in SQL. It's not there for a good reason; it would not be deterministic and that would give you quite headache trying to debug your application. However it's possible to pick one manually, it just takes some extra trickery to pull (some databases have extensions that could make it easier, but speaking of generic SQL).

So first you have to choose a criterion by which you will pick the one line you want to join. Say you want the one where the color comes alphabetically first (in real cases you'd probably have some priority or importance of something like that). The column you use must be unique for each fruit! You can calculate it by another join with group-by or by nested select. The nested select is IMO easier to write and understand. It would be:

```
(select min(Color) from FruitDetails as inner where inner.Fruit = Fruit.Fruit)
```

Now you join the tables with condition, that the color is that one, so:

```
select * from Fruit
    join FruitDetails as outer
        on outer.Fruit = Fruit.Fruit
        and outer.Color = (select min(Color) from FruitDetails as inner where inner.Fruit = Fruit.Fruit)
```

That assumes the `FruitDetails` table has a `Fruit` column which you forgot, but without which the join is not possible at all. And that it has a `unique(Fruit, Color)` constraint to guarantee there is only one line with the minimal color value for each fruit.

The other alternative with two joins would be:

```
select Fruit.* ThisDetails.*
    from Fruit
    join FruitDetails as ThisDetails using (Fruit)
    join FruitDetails as BestDetails using (Fruit)
    group by Fruit.*, ThisDetails.*
    having ThisDetails.Color = min(BestDetails.Color)
```

(`using (column)` is abbreviation for `onetable.column = othertable.column` in most, but not all, SQL variants)